# How can I create selectable templates similar to Microsoft Word?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm trying to create a scrollable window with templates as shown. I'm trying to make it evenly spaced with square or rectangular images with descriptions below them. Do I need to hard code this or is there a built in Qt widget for it?
[image: Screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 1):

For this you use a [QListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) in icon mode with custom items. In your custom items, you render the templates.

You should start off by getting into Qt's [Model/View](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) concept, with an emphasis on Delegates.

Comment: I got a downvote for this and I wonder who was so damn upset that this question was answered so they had to downvote the answer. When SO was started, a question like this was quite common btw. Nobody complained, everybody just moved on (or answered it). Think about it.